# how to use Selenium in python to select JQuery accordion element

Tags: jquery, selenium, accordion

I have an accordion unit in the html like following

```html
<div id="accordion">
  <h3>Section 1</h3>
  <div>
    <p> para1
    </p>
  </div>
  <h3>Section 2</h3>
  <div>
    <p> para2
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I can use find_element_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'Section 2')]") to find section 2, but i am not able to click it because it's a text.

Should I call the JQuery script first? What element should I search for to select Section 2?

Comment: So find out what actually has the `click` event.

Answer (score 0):

You can also tweak your xpath to point to the clickable part. Assuming the next `div` after the section is clickable, use `following-sibling`:

```
find_element_by_xpath("//h3[contains(., 'Section 2')]/following-sibling::div")
```

Comment: Yeah I figure out. I was using find_element[s]. So it returned a list which does not have click attribute.

Comment: @stan well, first you need to identify, which of the elements is responsible for opening an accordion - then it's just a matter of pointing your xpath to it. From what I see in the question - it's impossible for me to say where to click.